# Informatica - Get Date of Monday of a Week number

Tags: informatica, week-number

How to calculate the Monday date of a week using the week number in Informatica?!

Comment: Maybe this topic will help you achieve an answer, the question is about sunday, but changing it to monday wouldn't be too hard I guess. https://community.informatica.com/message/76927

Answer (score 0):

```
// We know week number and year.
int week = 42;
int year = 2014;

// Get calendar, clear it and set week number and year.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

// Now get the first day of week.
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: Hi Baliman, Hope you have written the logic using JAVA. Is der anyother way to do that without using JAVA transformation?